# jquery exclude a single element from All Selector ('*')

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am currently looking for a way to fadeOut all elements on a page apart from one, without manually fading out each element.

I cam across the jQuery All Selector ('*') which does exactly as i want:

```
$('*').delay(0).fadeOut('fast');
```

The above fades out every element on the page.

My question is, with this can i then only show one certain element after then above has occured? I would like to show one single element, and thought this would be the best way of doing things.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: how do you know which element is the one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('*:not("body,html")')// select all expect body and html
.not(".foo")// now hide our selector ".foo"
.fadeOut('fast');
```

reference **[not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** can also use [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/pFWur/7/)**

Comment: this doesnt seem to work? $('*').not('#info').delay(0).fadeOut('fast');

Comment: if my elements is within another div and then that div has another parent div, then this doesnt work. Thanks for the answer, i have come up with an alternative now

Comment: show your html hope i will give you solution and you can add your parent div reference in not() or :not() then it will work @danyo

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because the `*` selector will also take the `<html>` and `<body>` tags themselves, and any element is part of them. So to solve this, you must exclude those tags exclusively then exclude the desired elements(s) using the `.not()` method passing a selector:

```
var excludedTags = ["html", "body"];
$("*").not(excludedTags.join(",")).not(".foo").delay(0).fadeOut('fast');
```

This will fade out everything except elements with class *foo*.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/pFWur/6/).